# How to make the arrows animate in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, geometry, gganimate

How can I make the arrow move  from one end  to other. I want to represent an energy flow.

```
plot <- ggplot(combined_total_active_2, aes(x = 0, y = 0)) +
  coord_fixed()+
  theme_void()+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#11141a"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#11141a"))

# Add lines connecting the circles
plot <- plot +
  
  geom_curve(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = -1, yend = 0),
             curvature = 0, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.21, "inches")), 
             color = "#ffc559", size = 1.2, alpha = 0.6)+

  geom_segment(aes(x = -3, y = 0, xend = 3, yend = 0), color = "#ffc559",
                               size = 1.5, lineend = "round") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = -3, xend = 0, yend = 3), color = "#ffc559",
                               size = 1.5, lineend = "round")

plot
```

Output:
**Two line segments and 1 arrow**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `gganimate` you could do:

```r
library(gganimate)

p <- ggplot(data.frame(val = seq(3, -3, -0.1), time = 1:61)) +
  geom_segment(arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.21, "inches")), 
               color = "#ffc559", linewidth = 1.2, alpha = 0.6,
               aes(x = 3, y = 0, xend = val, yend = 0)) +
  geom_hline(color = "#ffc559", linewidth = 1.2, yintercept = 0) +
  geom_vline(color = "#ffc559", linewidth = 1.2, xintercept = 0) +
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(-3, 3), ylim = c(-3, 3)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#11141a"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#11141a")) +
  transition_manual(time)

animate(p, fps = 61)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To change to a filled circle we can just do

```r
p <- ggplot(data.frame(val = seq(3, -3, -0.1), time = 1:61)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = val, y = 0), size = 8, color = "#ffc559") +
  geom_hline(color = "#ffc559", linewidth = 1.2, yintercept = 0) +
  geom_vline(color = "#ffc559", linewidth = 1.2, xintercept = 0) +
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(-3, 3), ylim = c(-3, 3)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#11141a"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#11141a")) +
  transition_manual(time)

animate(p, fps = 61)
```

[image]

Comment: Great!!. How can I add other shapes than arrow

Comment: @NevinThomas it depends on which shapes you want to add. It's easy to add one of the built-in point shapes, but if you want an arbitrary polygon that's a bit harder.

Comment: I just want a filled circle shape. Thanks!

Comment: And what do you want it to do @NevinThomas? Is it to replace the arrow, or move on the other axis, or what?

Comment: to replace the arrow with circle shape

Comment: Edited code looks same

Comment: My bad @NevinThomas - fixed now.